# Tags are too long vertically in anonymous and low rep post feedback

Tags: bug, tags, design, 10k-tools, post-feedback

There seems to be a bug where tags are too long vertically in the [overrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/overrated?filter=all), [most helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/most-helpful?filter=all), [least helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/least-helpful?filter=all) tabs of the [anonymous and low rep post feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback) page of the 10k tools.

[image: screenshot of bug in tags]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 96.0.1 (64-bit), 1920x1080, rev 2022.1.24.41249

Comment: This appears to happen to all questions in this list.

Comment: @SebastianSimon for me it happens with some but not with others.