# The "Edit" button on the Tags page escapes its bounding box when the tag name is too long

Tags: bug, tags, design, tags-page

On the [tags page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags?page=162&tab=name) the "Edit" button is displayed incorrectly when the tag name is too long. (Need edit privileges (2k rep) on the site to see the button.)

(printscreen from [StackOverflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)):

[image]

Comment: What edit button? I don't see any button near tag names, and don't understand the language anyway. If specific to that site, please post on its meta not here.

Comment: Also, please link to the page you posted screenshot of, the homepage is not relevant.

Comment: @Shadow, The "edit" button is circled. It's language is Russian. I [post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12729/) it on meta StakcOverflow на русском, but they said to write here

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard, I've added link to need page.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard repro-ed on the [SO Tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMogU.png and here is the  [sede query to find long tag names](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1753180) I guess it is less prominent on english sites due to the characters taking less space.

Comment: Well most people here don't have 2k rep on that site so won't see the button, and the bug.

Comment: Check out the "tag too long" duplicates (such as: [Tags are too long vertically in anonymous and low rep post feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375540/tags-are-too-long-vertically-in-anonymous-and-low-rep-post-feedback)) and add your browser version to your question, as shown in that link.

Comment: @Rob no, this is not a duplicate at all. Totally different bug. (Sadly many users follow the first vote, so I'll check on this to reopen if closed.)